# Pointing webserver to load .html page and not subdirectory index

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess

So I have been searching for a few hours now and have not found the answer to my problem.

So I have a website that I was wanting to take the page extension off e.g. .html / .php etc.. and I had found that I could include the below code in the .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

I have now added that code and it works great for removing .html from my pages. However now I have come into a new problem. I have a page and directory both named 'guides' on the root of my public_html folder. Now when I enter the url 'www.mydomain.com/guides' the index of the guides directory is showing rather than the guides.html page that I am wanting to display.

I am wondering what would be the best way to get around this and make my server look for the webpage first rather than display the guides directory index.

I have been looking at RewriteRule's but it seems to be all wordpress content and does not work with my non wordpress website.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Occam's razor: Either place the guides.html page inside the guides directory (and rename it to index.html), or rename guides.html to something similar but different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to change the name of the directory or the file to something different. RewriteRule can not rewrite a directory request to file as the directory request is first handled by `mod-dir` (directory module) .

If you do not want to change the name, then you can  turn off  `DirectorySlash` on your server using the following line in htaccess :

```
 DirectorySlash off
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash